# Java: String to 7 bits hashing

Tags: java, string, hash, code-coverage, bit-manipulation

I had a requirement where I have a set of Strings which are not known beforehand (for e.g. "phy", "link", "maca")

and I have 2 programs where I have only 7 bits to send across to communicate about the string.

If I knew the strings before hand I can say "phy"=1 "link"=2 and so on but I want to automate this where I have 2 functions in both the program with some way of encoding etc.

```
    private int getHash(String agent) {        
      return 0;
    }
    private String getAgentIDfromHash(int hash) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }
```

So the int will be a 7 bit int. I can try XORing all the chars in String but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it?
any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The standard String `hashCode` function is designed to be well distributed.

So you could simply take 7 bits from `agent.hashCode()` (the ones you want but preferably the lower bits).

Note that you can't have a very low collision probability with 7 bits, whatever you do. 2⁷ is only 128. You should probably find a property of the strings set enabling a better solution.

Comment: any 7 bits will be well distributed?

Comment: The lower bits are of course better but I recall having read studies saying that it wasn't so bad for any set of bytes. Note that it's a reasonable proposition, not the best one, hashCode is sometimes criticized.

Comment: if I use "phy".hashCode()&0x7f .. for the set of strings i know I get different values.. my strings wont be more than 5-6 chars

Answer (score 1):

with such a small number of bits you'll have to take extra care that no collision occur. The minimum would be that programs first internally check that they're not creating collisions with their own (known) part of the names.

The ideal situation would be that both programs know the whole keyset, so that they can produce a mapping of 7bit-IDs-to-name and that the mapping would be the same on both side (whatever the set of keys were).